# Why is the output 'undeclared' for this JavaScript Code?

Tags: javascript, string

I have created a simple JS method for reversing a string. But when I execute the code, I get the output as `UndeclarednoynaCUndeclared` in the alert box. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```js
function Reverse(str) {
    var len = str.length;
    for( var i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        var rev = str[i] + rev;
    }
    alert(rev);
}
Reverse('Canyon');
```

Comment: Which browser you use? I checked ff, chrome, opera and edge and getting undefined, not undeclared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that `rev` have no value initially (is `undefined` or `undeclared`), assigning it to empty string is the fix for the first `undefined`.

Last `undefined` appears b/c of `length`'s element of string never exists (b/c start calculating from 0), so you need to replace:

`i <= len` to

`i < len`

```js
function Reverse(str){
    var len = str.length;
    var rev = ''; 
    for( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rev = str[i] + rev;
    }
    alert(rev);
}

Reverse('Canyon');
```

Comment: This explanation is incorrect, as variables declared with var are hoisted to the top of the function scope

Comment: @Ferrybig, I understand that variables are hoisted. What do you mean by “to the top of the function scope”?

Comment: Good point, actually under the hood js move (hoist) `var rev` outside the loop to top to the function scope (the very beginning of the function), but as there is no value in `rev` then it's `undefined`. So the actual fix is in assigning empty string into `rev`.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that output because of [`Hoisting`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) of variable `rev`. The variable is declared first with the value `undefined` before being used in the statement `var rev = str[i] + rev;`. Declare `var rev = ''` before `for` loop. Another point is that your loop is executing one extra time.
So change `i <= len` to `i < len`.

But you can take the advantages of some built-in functions here to get the output quite easily.

You can simply use `split()` to get an array from the string. Then `reverse()` that array. Finally `join()` that array to get the reverse string.

```js
function Reverse(str){
  str = str.split('').reverse().join('');
  alert(str);
}

Reverse('Canyon');
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
//using charAt() method in conditional statements
function Reverse(str) {
  if (str === "")
    return "";
  else
    return Reverse(str.substr(1)) + str.charAt(0);
}
alert(Reverse("Canyon"));
```